# How can I write functional and parallelizable code without using large memory?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to do an imperative code in functional way. The problem that I am facing is that the functional way blows up the memory. Is there a collection type in functional languages (here Scala) that can be consumed and garbage collected immediately whenever not needed?

I am simulating interaction between agents, here monkeys, over a year using minute time-steps. Some parts of this interaction is parallelizable and expensive,  and one single part is not parallelizable.

The most logical and non-imperative way to do this is to divide the code into functions and run the functions in parallel for each agent.

My problem is that I have hundreds of thousands of agents and hundreds of thousands of time-steps. This blows up the memory usage, which forces me to do the code in imperative and immutable way with no functions.

I am asking how to implement the following example in functional way without consuming much memory. Is there some functional-trick that I am missing?

```scala
import scala.util.Random
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq


val timeSteps = 1000
val numMonkeys = 100

// resource intensive function, depends on the previous state at time 't-1'.
val monkeyState: (Int) => Vector[Int] = (ts) =>
  Vector.tabulate(ts)(t => (t - 1) + Random.nextInt(3)) 
// resource intensive function calculate the eating behavior of monkeys at each time-step.
val monkeyEating: (Vector[Int]) => Vector[Int] = (ss) => ss.map(_ % 2) 

// make Seq of monkeys eating (parallelizable)
val monkeysList = ParSeq.fill(numMonkeys)(monkeyEating(monkeyState(timeSteps)))


val resourceConsumption =
  for (t <- 0 to timeSteps;
       mon <- monkeysList.toSeq) yield {
    // Estimate resource interactions between monkeys, mon(t), (non parallelizable)
  ??? // uses mon(t)
  }
```

Comment: The analogy with `Int` is kind of hard to follow... you mention that your loop body uses `mon(t)`, but does it use all the `mon` vector as well? Also, if the loop body is not parallelizable, why do you iterate over a ParSeq?

Comment: @oowekyala I corrected the parallel loop, as you stated it should not be parallel. As regards the first comment, the function relies on the monkeys eating behaviors at time 't', i.e., loops through each monkey at time 't'.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ZIO. ZIO is simplest and leak-free Scala library for pure functional programming (with ability to interrupt an IO at any point)

```scala
/*
import $ivy.`dev.zio::zio-streams:1.0.0-RC12`
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:2.0.0-RC2`
*/
import cats.implicits._
import zio._
import zio.console._
import zio.stream._

import scala.util.Random

object Hello extends App {
  def run(args: List[String]) = {
    val monkeyState: Int => Stream[Nothing, Int] =
      n => Stream.unfold(n)(i => if (i > 0) (Random.nextInt(3) -> (i - 1)).some else none)

    def monkeyEating(xs: Stream[Nothing, Int]): Stream[Nothing, Int] =
      xs.map(_ % 2)

    val numMonkeys = 100

    val timeSteps = 1000

    val res: Stream[Nothing, Int] = Stream.flattenPar(numMonkeys)(
      Stream.fromIterable(0 to timeSteps).map(_ => monkeyEating(monkeyState(timeSteps)))
    )

    res.foreach(i => putStrLn(s"$i")).fold(_ => 0, _ => 1)
  }
}
```